# Environment variable not accepting for azure

Tags: node.js, azure, environment-variables, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have defined environment variables for azure in terminal like as below,

```
SET AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=accountname
SET SAS_TOKEN="sr=c&sp=rwl&sig=signatureKey%3D&sv=2017-04-17&se=2018-03-10"
```

After defining the varibale, i have called these variables inside the azure blob storage function like,

```
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT= process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT;
SAS_TOKEN = process.env.SAS_TOKEN;
var blobUri = "http://"+AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT+".blob.core.windows.net";
var blobService = azureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, SAS_TOKEN).withFilter(new azureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());
blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'sparks-events-data', fileToWrite, function(error, result, response) {
if (!error) {
    console.log("upload successful..");
} else {
    console.log(error);
}});
```

When i run above file i am getting error like

> StorageError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure
>   the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature.

But when i call the SAS token directly inside the code it works fine. I am using like this

```
var sasKey = "sr=c&sp=rwl&sig=signatureKey%3D&sv=2017-04-17&se=2018-03-10";
var blobService = azureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sasKey ).withFilter(new azureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());
```

it works fine for me. I need to set the SAS token as environment variable. Here what i am missing. Please someone suggest me a solution for this.
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

`export` those env vars instead. Exporting a variable causes the variable to be inherited by subsequent processes started in *that* shell.

```
export SAS_TOKEN="..."
```

You may want to take a look at this npm package before rolling your own *env var secrets* handling logic. We already cracked this, as a people —
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

In Windowsland, just use `set`, but make sure your Node process starts in the same terminal window:

```
C:\lab> set KEY="secret"

C:\lab> type app.js
let key = process.env.KEY;
console.log('KEY is ' + key);

C:\lab> node app.js
KEY is "secret"
```

Watch out for those quotes!

Comment: `export` command is used in linux machines right. I am trying to set that in windows machine.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyother way to declare this environment variable with special characters instead using npm package

Comment: What's stopping you from using special chars right now?

Comment: This is the value i need to set as environment variable `sr=c&sp=rwl&sig=signatureKey%3D&sv=2017-04-17&se=2018-03-10`. But when i read it's showing it comes with double quotes

Comment: You could borrow the parse logic from dotenv - https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/95aa929a1dae749c204edfb3ce3df99490a77a24/lib/main.js#L32. Or you could just use dotenv :)